# How to access excel cell using cell name with java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, vba

I am trying to convert Excel VBA to Java
I want to compare contents of a cell by using cell name like they do in VBA

eg.Sheets("sheetname").Range("cellname").Value = somevalue

how do I convert the above example to java

Comment: didn't you find any example at google.com ?

Comment: I am aware of wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(1); but is there any method  to get the just the  cell name  instead of using getRow(1).getCell(1)

Comment: You need to show us what did you tried and what making you blocked with some example. Basically, current output and expected output.

Comment: @Natasha Thakur: As often here, the ones who had voted closing this question, seems not to have any clue what the question is about. So users are forced to ask the questions here as if the audience has not a clue. So you would had must explain in detail what `Range("cellname")` does in Excel VBA ;-). Well...;-). But you could have a look at: [Quick-Guide Named Ranges and Named Cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Named+Ranges+and+Named+Cells).